# Add port to all URLs using environment variable

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I'm using environment variable `apiHost` to set the server URL.

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiHost: ':8080'
};
```

This gives the following URL :
`http://myserver/:8080` and I would like to have `http://myserver:8080/`.

The app (backend and frontend) will be sent to multiple clients, therefore there is no common server URL to set. 
How can I achieve that (even using a method other than environment one) ?

EDIT: Example of use of the environment varible

```
getProducts() {
    return this.httpClient.get<Product[]>(environment.apiHost + 'products');
  }
```

Comment: How do you get the URL you mention?

Comment: `apiHost: 'http://myserver:8080/'`.

Comment: So you have your apiHost set to `http://myserver:8080/` in your environment file?

Comment: @trichetriche As I mentioned, the app will be sent to multiple clients and they will host the backend on their own server.

Comment: So they won't have the same API address and will have to overwrite it, and not just the port. That's what environment files are made for.

Comment: Search your code for use of `environment.apiHost` and change its logic (or post it here). I would also recommend to have apiHost without ':'

Comment: @androniennn is there a thing called `apiPort` ?  you could try that. or use `apiUrl` and create environment.*.ts file for each.

Comment: @trichetriche Exactly. The app won't have the same API address, every client has its own API address (that could be `localhost` if the client chooses to implement it locally).

Comment: So, use the `apiHost` property as the API address, and not only as the API port.

Comment: @Andriy I edited my question.

Comment: @androniennn where do you set `myserver` technically port `8080` is part of the server name

Comment: @trichetriche If I revoke the port from the environment variable, the API address will be something like this `http://myserver` so the requests will not succeed (the backend will be surely at the 8080 port (Embedded Spring Boot Tomcat server)).

Comment: Ok I don't know if you're being oblivious on purpose, so I'll just make an answer to you explaining how it works.

Comment: You can try this: `return this.httpClient.get<Product[]>(`${location.protocol}://${location.hostname}${environment.apiHost}products`);`
If your code is within service, you can pass your location object (or creaeted URL) to service

Answer (score 0):

Environment files are files that are used to configure your application.

When used, they can change properties automatically, depending on the environment (or configuration in A6) you chose to build your application with.

Let's work this out with an example. Let's say you have two clients, A and B, and you want to let them chose their API address.

You'll start by creating the first one, `environment.ts`, which is the base one :

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api: 'http://localhost:8080';
};
```

Now, your clients give you their API addresses. You will have to write a new file for each client.

**environment.A.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  api: 'http://www.A.com:8080';
};
```

**environment.B.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  api: 'http://www.B.com:8080';
};
```

Now, in your services, all you have to do is request the environment file (the base one). For instance :

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment'

export class UserService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUsers() { return this.http.get<any>(environment.api); }
}
```

Once your application is done, you will have to **build it**. That's where the environments are being switched.

For the first client, you will run this one (considering you have set up your `angular-cli.json` file correctly)

```
ng build --prod --env A
```

For the second one :

```
ng build --prod --env B
```

With this, you **won't have to do anything else** : your HTTP calls will be sent to the correct API addresses.

If you only input the port in your environments, this means that you have hard coded the URL in your application, meaning your clients won't be able to change it.

And if you didn't hard coded the URL but it's not in the environment files, then you are not following the best practices advised by Angular. Hell worst, you're not using the framework to its full potential.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. I'm already using this in some of my projects where I know the clients hosts API. In my current project, the app will be stored in a such 'market', where the user will download the app (normally a backend file(jar) and a frontend directory), launch the backend file that will launch the server on port 8080. So I'll never have an idea of where the clients will store their app. So my idea was to just add (concatenate) `8080` on the `/` URL. Perhaps that there is a more robust solution, "je suis preneur" !

Comment: So in every case your API address would be `http://localhost`, only the port would change ? Because right now, from your comment, what I understand is that you are always running the server on port 8080, and only the domain will change.

Comment: The port will be always 8080 as I configured it that way. But I remember that I had a problem setting `localhost:8080` as apiHost, I think that it was with CORS, and that I read somewhere that I have to set the server URL and not localhost. I will reproduce that and will let you know. I hope that you well understood what I'd like to have... And I'm really open to other ideas.

Comment: If you have more issues, consider opening a discussion on my answer, so that we can speak french and you explain your issue to me without polluting the comments !

Comment: Good idea. Here is it : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176643/add-port-to-all-urls-using-environment-variable